# Database performance benchmark

Tags: mysql, sql-server, performance, oracle

Any good articles out there comparing Oracle vs SQL Server vs MySql in terms of performance?

I'd like to know things like:

- INSERT performance
- SELECT performance
- Scalability under heavy load

Based on some real examples in order to gain a better understanding about the different RDBMS.

Comment: you would be better stating what you intend to be running on the RDBMS. Too many params: hardware differences, OLTP versus OLAP, high availability, clustering, SANS. ORACLE and SQL Server obviously scale......etc

Comment: Ok, just some simple examples to start with. For instance, I've found that SQLServer is able to handle much more load than Firebird with C# applications. All benchmarks will be biased, but having a good collection of links will really help.

Comment: Firebird vs SQL Server is really comparing apples to oranges. The three databases you mentioned above are all apples. Slightly different (but largely irrelevant) performance, slightly different (and possibly extremely relevant) feature sets.

Comment: Too open ended. For example, by heavy load do you mean concurrent transactions ? Are they doing conflicting inserts/updates ? Go to the vendors (or agents) with YOUR requirements and ask what hardware (and database editions) would be required to support it.

Comment: Yes, I mean concurrent INSERT/UPDATE transactions from, let's say, 200 concurrent users.

Comment: here is a benchmark I've found so far http://www.lacsc.org/papers/Paper21.pdf‎

Answer (score 4):

The question is really too broad to be answered because it all depends on what you want to do as there is no general "X is better than Y" benchmark without qualifying "at doing Z" or otherwise giving it some kind of context.

The short answer is: it really doesn't matter. Any of those will be fast enough for your needs. I can say that with 99% certainty. Even MySQL can scale to billions of rows.

That being said, they *do* vary. As just one example, I wrote a post about a very narrow piece of functionality: join and aggregation performance. See [Oracle vs MySQL vs SQL Server: Aggregation vs Joins](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/07/oracle-vs-mysql-vs-sql-server.html).

Comment: I guess that's what I said in my comment, but I just didn't say it as well!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such benchmarks do exist, but they cannot be published, as Oracle's licensing prohibits publishing such things.

At least, that is the case to the best of my knowledge. I've seen a few published which do not name Oracle specifically, but instead say something like "a leading RDBMS" when they are clearly talking about Oracle, but I don't know whether that gets around it.

On the other hand, Oracle now own MySQL, so perhaps they won't care so much, or perhaps they will. Who knows.